# Google Drive Realtime API: using files as database

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

[I see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17622257/4275251) that Google supports both standard files and shortcuts. I do not get which format should I create for storing my model permanently and if I can do that at all. Can I exploit google realtime to use as simple cloud storage (previous generations of programmers referred to the cloud storage as `database`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have binary contents, use a standard file.  Otherwise, use a shortcut file.

If are using the realtime API and plan to store all data using it, then you can use a shortcut file and associate the realtime document with it.

I'm not sure what you mean by simple cloud storage, but you could use the realtime API to store arbitrary key value pairs.

Comment: I basically plan to store data and use Realtime API for that. I just do not get where is data stored when it is attached to shortcut.

Comment: In the case of the realtime API, it's stored in the realtime document.  For other uses, it may be on an apps custom server, for example.  It's up to the app.

Comment: Than you for the response but it causes more questions that cleans up. When you say `up to the app` you mean non-realtime API application, right, since realtime app uses realtime document for the storage. How long is it stored? Does document disappear as soon as all collaborators tear down the connections or I can rely on the document using it as simple database (atomic and durable) indeed? How is `collaboration document` related to the `shortcuts` and `standard files`? Thanks.

Comment: When attached to a shortcut file, the realtime document persists forever.  When attached to a standard file, it lasts until the binary contents of that file change.  So if you use a shortcut file you can rely on the document being durable.

Comment: I am getting it like database is created 'somewhere in the clouds' whereas google drive is just placeholder to your created databases (aka shortcuts). Thanks.